# Executing a command at a specific time and ending it at specific time or when a condition is verified

Tags: bash, shell, sh, task

I'm trying to execute and kill a process programatically.

```
command... | at 8:00
TASK_PID=$!
kill $TASK_PID | at 5:00
```

I should be able to start the command at 8:00 am and stop it at 5:00 pm, right?

If this code is correct I want to add 3 conditions that check the last lines of a file and kill the process in case the conditions are verified.
I know I should use the command `tail` and then check if the returned string **contains** the strings I'm looking for.

It should be roughly something like this:

```
STR = tail -f $FILE

if [[ $STR == *"Condition1"* ]]; then
  kill $TASK_PID
fi

 if [[ $STR == *"Condition2"* ]]; then
      kill $TASK_PID
    fi

 if [[ $STR == *"Condition3"* ]]; then
      kill $TASK_PID
    fi
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `kill $TASK_PID | at 5:00` you should keep the kill commands in your above `cleanup.sh` script where they are nested within your conditionals.

Of course, you will need to store the PID of `command` in order to kill it later. Example syntax for some `command` with optional parameters `...` to run at 8 AM would be `command ... & echo $! > pidfile | at 8:00`. This would pipe the PID into a file named `pidfile`.

Then run `./cleanup.sh pathToFile pathToPIDFile | at 17:00` (24-hour format or specify AM/PM).

So, assuming they all reside in the same directory the command to initiate `cleanup.sh` to check some `testfile` file at 5 PM would be
`./cleanup.sh testfile pidfile | at 17:00`

Here is the code for `cleanup.sh`:

```
#$1 is the testfile passed as an argument
#& creates tail as a background process that terminates when finished
STR=$(tail $1 &)

#$2 is the pidfile passed as an argument
PID=$(cat pidfile)

if [[ "$STR" == *"Condition1"* ]]; then
    kill -9 $PID
fi

if [[ "$STR" == *"Condition2"* ]]; then
    kill -9 $PID
fi

if [[ "$STR" == *"Condition3"* ]]; then
    kill -9 $PID
fi
```

Note for others that the double `[[` bracket conditions are not POSIX compliant and the conditions may have to be rewritten for this to work with different (non-bash) shells.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the focus was on the command scheduling and that the script portion was roughly pseudo-code to show your logic. I will certainly edit my answer with the exact code for the script.

Comment: Please check if my updated answer matches what you logically are trying to do (and of course, also check that it works). My answer assumes that you aren't always sure when you start the `command` process when you wish it to end. If you always plan on knowing both the start and end time beforehand then that would mean you could combine that logic into one script and pass in `testfile` and some `endtime` as arguments, thus circumventing the need to store the PID in a file.